# User profile status in CSS

Tags: html, css, styles

I am trying to implement a user profile status bar in my webpage. For this I have done the following:

```
<ul style="width:250px;background-color:#F5F5F5;">
    <li style="width: 20%;background-color:#abb230;"/>
</ul>
```

For this code I am getting the result below:

[image]

So here I want to remove the bullet to the left of the green bar, and make the green bar flush left.

I have tried doing this:

```
<ul style="width:250px;background-color:#F5F5F5;list-style:none;">
    <li style="width: 20%;background-color:#abb230;"/>
</ul>
```

But this makes the entire `<ul>` element disappear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
ul {
    width: 250px;
    background-color: #F5F5F5;
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0;
}
li {
    width: 20%;
    background-color: #abb230;
    height: 20px;
}
```

[**DEMO here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/97Xq9/)

Answer (score 1):

```
ul
{
    list-style-type: none;
    list-style-position:inside;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
```

This would help you

Comment: I have tried this but its not working, by doing this the whole ul gets disappeared

Answer (score 1):

Have the following styling on the "ul".

```
list-style:none;
```

Quick pointer. Avoid so much inline styling. Separate presentation logic from the structure